# I am searching for Maker Board/Mini PC to run Apps made with .NET/.NET Core

Tags: processor, linux, windows, mini-pc

I am loooking for a Mini-PC or a Maker Board which is capable of running Apps made with .NET/.Net Core.

So it can be Windows and Linux Machines. But they need to support the .NET Runtime.

My Requirements:

- Shouldn‘t be that powerfull to save energy
- The machine should have expandable storage for RAM (so nothing hard soldered)
- The Chip of the machine shiuld match these chipsets: x64
  x86
  ARM32
  ARM64
- I would prefer a Linux-based Architecture. Because for Windows you need to buy licenses.

Does anyone have some recommendations here or maybe had the same requirements and found a suitable machine or maker board?

Comment: Is System76 Meerkat a good one?

Comment: @Irsu85 I think this is a little bit too expensive. I just went with a cheap Mini-PC and especially this one here: https://www.intel.de/content/www/de/de/products/systems-devices/sku/h92878982/acer-veriton-en2580/specifications.html

Comment: Ok, but anything can run .net things which can run the OSes which are supported by it. I think your specification could be more narrow. In practice, you will likely have some RAM requirement what a configuration might not fulfill.

Comment: [raspberry pi](https://www.raspberrypi.com/products/raspberry-pi-4-model-b/)? not upgradable RAM, but very inexpensive to just buy a new one if you need more. Assuming you can find one for sale and in stock.